# c3js onload change color

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, c3.js

I am looking for a method to change a scatter chat's plot's color, and i found a example using d3 codes within the chart http://jsfiddle.net/ot19Lyt8/9/

```
           onmouseover: function (d) {
  d3.select(d3.selectAll("circle")[0][d.index]).style("fill", "red");
  d3.select(d3.selectAll("circle")[1][d.index]).style("fill", "red");
 d3.select(d3.selectAll("circle")[3][d.index]).style("fill", "red");
            },
```

As you see the plot color would change when you on hover a plot but I'd like to modify it, in order to given different color for each plot onload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi as far as i understood you want to see the different colors of plot points by default.

jsfiddle for the same:-
http://jsfiddle.net/ot19Lyt8/104/

code for this:-

```
color: function (color, d) {
            return  colors[d.index];
        },
```

Comment: thanks, i think i should be able to finish the task now

Comment: Sorry i got an extra question , am i able to make a fix color set?